# .bashrc variable equivalent in windows

Tags: reactjs, windows, github, environment-variables

I need to set a GitHub token for my react project , I am using windows 10 , I know that in mac I should set variable like below and copy the token and export it as a shell environment variable.

For example, edit one of the following files: ~/.bashrc, ~/.zshrc or ~/.profile and add the following line , but I need to do that in windows and don't know how

```
export GITHUBTOKEN='sometoken'
```

I also used [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-set-environment-variables-using-powershell#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Set%20environment%20variables%20using%20PowerShell%3F%20To,otherwise%2C%20a%20new%20environment%20variable%20will%20be%20created.) but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

set environment variable using Powershell with below piece of code :

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('GITHUBTOKEN','token')
```